# Ajax Call from JS to Controller is too slow

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I using the MVC Application and i am calling controller through ajax call after loading the page.but when i am calling method from controller through ajax it taking more than 4 mins to hit the controller breakpoint, can any one tell what is the problem

Comment: You need to share more details, snippets of code otherwise there could be any kind of possibilities of slowness which is hard to explain by just reading the description,